# Returning reactivated users teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata, lag, teradata-sql-assistant, lead

I am trying to form a query for returning, reactivated and WAU as defined below:

- Returning WAU - active last week
- WAU - not active last week, but active within last 30 days
- Reactivated WAU – not seen in 30+ days

I have table for past 60 days containing cust_id, login date but cant lag function to work (Teradata ODBC connection). I keep getting this error:

> [3706] Syntax error: Data Type "logindate" does not match a Defined
> Type name. My format is: select .... lag(logindate, 1) over (partition
> by cust_id order by 1 asc) as lag_ind from ( ....

Please help for the 3 cases above.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate to get the expected answer:

```
select cust_id,
   case
     when max(logindate) > current_date - 7  -- active last week
       then 'Returning WAU' 
     when max(logindate) > current_date - 30 -- not active last week, but active within last 30 days
       then 'WAU'
     else 'Reactivated WAU'                  –- not seen in 30+ days
   end
from tab
group by 1
```

Regarding the issue with LAG, this has been introduced in 16.10, before you have to rewrite:

```
lag(logindate, 1)
over (partition by cust_id
      order by col asc) as lag_ind

max(logindate)
over (partition by cust_id
      order by col asc
      rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as lag_ind
```

Hint: never use ORDER BY 1 in an OLAP function, here it's the literal value one and not the first column.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for the help. This is not helping for reporting on weekly basis ... basically I have expanded my table to past 3 months  and trying to produce a report as 
week # |  Returning WAU | WAU | Reactivated WAU
July 04 (ending Saturday) | xxxx | xxx | xxxx